Is this a vector space: $k(x,y,z)=(kx,y,z)$?
if $ (x,y,z), (x',y',z') \in V$ then lets define $(x,y,z)+ (x',y',z') =(x+x',y+y',z+z') $ and $k(x,y,z)=(kx,y,z)$ is $V$ a vector space?
My answer was no since $(x,y,z)+-1(x,y,z) \ne 0$ so there is no unique member $-z$ st $z-z=0$  but my friend disagreed with me saying that $A+-1B$ doesn't mean $A-B$ or $-A\ne -1A$ and this is indeed a vector space. we spent sometime arguing and I realised we don't make a good argument and we (at least one of us) just didn't undertant the meaning of

For each vector $a \in V \, \exists  $ a unique vector $-a$ st $a-a =0$


You are correct in saying that $V$ is not a vector space, but your friend is right in saying that your argument is wrong. Indeed, within the axiom (which would be more correctly written as)

For each vector $\alpha \in V$, there exists a unique vector $-\alpha$ such that $\alpha + (-\alpha) = 0_V$,

the symbols $-\alpha$ do not necessarily refer to the same thing as $(-1)\alpha$. With that in mind, your set $V$ with the addition rule given satisfies this axiom: for a given vector $\alpha = (x,y,z)$, $-\alpha = (-x,-y,-z)$ is its unique multiplicative inverse.
That said, the fact that $-\alpha \neq (-1) \alpha$ is evidence that $V$ violates one of the vector space axioms. Consider the following axiom:

For any constants $c_1,c_2$ and any vector $\alpha \in V$, $(c_1 + c_2)\alpha = c_1 \alpha + c_2 \alpha$.

We can see that this statement does not hold with $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = -1$. Indeed, for a vector $\alpha = (x,y,z)$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
(c_1 + c_2)\alpha &= 0\alpha = (0,y,z)\\
c_1\alpha + c_2 \alpha &= 1\alpha + (-1)\alpha 
\\ & = (x,y,z) + (-x,y,z) = (0,2y,2z),
\end{align*}
$$
and as long as $\alpha$ is selected such that either $y$ or $z$ is non-zero, we can see that the results are indeed different.

When $V$ actually is a vector space, the fact that $-\alpha = (-1)\alpha$ can be proved as follows. First, note that $0\alpha = 0_V$; this can be proved with the approach presented in this post. With that starting point, we can use the distribution of scalar addition to see that
$$
0\alpha = 0_V \implies\\
(1 + (-1)) \alpha = 0_V \implies\\
1 \alpha + (-1)\alpha = 0_V \implies\\
\alpha + (-1) \alpha = 0_V \implies\\
(-1)\alpha = -\alpha.
$$

Your space fails to be a vector space because your multiplication does not distribute over addition: $$(a+b)\cdot(x,y,z)=((a+b)x,y,z)=(ax+bx,y,z)$$
$$a(x,y,z) + b(x,y,z)= (ax,y,z)+(bx,y,z)=(ax+bx,y+y,z+z)$$
These are not equal unless $y=z=0$.
